# Newly made desktop will not turn on

Tags: desktop

I just finished building my first desktop. I have plugged everything in (or so I think) and when I go to turn it on for an instant the light on my cpu's cooler turns on and all the fans in the case and in the gpu start to spin. Then they all stop.

here are my specs: http://pcpartpicker.com/p/Phngyc

Please help and thank you

Comment: Reconnect everything, try with the absolute minimum installed start ruling out possible causes

Comment: Seen this happen a few times, it always was an improper placement of the CPU cooler. Somehow it just didn't makes proper contact and out of safety of blowing the cpu the system shuts off.

Comment: if there was too much cooling paste between the cooler and the  cpu could that be it?

Comment: @LPChip I tried taking it off and putting it back on and nothing changed, I even took off some of the extra cooling paste that I used so now there is a lot less. How much should there be? or is it probably not an issue and it is something else?

Comment: "How much should there be" -> As little as possible. The cooling paste is less efficient at transfering heat than the cooler. It is just there to fill small air hole.

Comment: Try checking how you plugged in the power supply. Is there a plug you didn't plug in.. or is there a plug where you plugged the wrong thin into it

Comment: Also check the seating of the RAM modules, they can be quite hard to get in place correctly.

Comment: the power source is plugged into the wall correctly, the ram is fully in their places, i removed the extra paste and it didnt work, i then took out my liquid cooling unit and put on the cooling unit that came with the cpu, it still doesnt work....